# How to trigger fieldset factory in ZF3

Tags: php, factory, zend-form, zend-framework3, fieldset

I need to use factory for fieldset. I know how to do it for form, but how to do it for fieldset?

The form code is:

```
namespace Application\Form;

use Application\Fieldset\Outline;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class Message extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('message'); 
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');    
        $this->add([
            'type' => Outline::class,
            'options' => [
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => true,
            ],
        ]);
        $this->add([
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => [
                'type' => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Send',
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

As one can see above the line `'type' => Outline::class,`
 tells parser to create fieldset object. But how to tell parser to create fieldset object with a custom fieldset factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormElementManager` is extending from `ServiceManager` so you have to config it same as service manager. Here's an example

```
class MyModule {
     function getConfig(){
           return [
               /* other configs */
               'form_elements' => [   // main config key for FormElementManager
                   'factories' => [
                        \Application\Fieldset\Outline::class => \Application\Fieldset\Factory\OutlineFactory::class
                   ]
               ]
               /* other configs */
           ];
     }
}
```

With this config, when you call `\Application\Fieldset\Outline::class`, `\Application\Fieldset\Factory\OutlineFactory::class` will be triggered by `FormElementManager`. Everything same as `ServiceManager`. You will call your fieldset as via service manager;

```
$container->get('FormElementManager')->get(\Application\Fieldset\Outline::class);
```

Also you can call it in forms/fieldsets via `getFormFactory` method;

```
function init() { // can be construct method too, nothing wrong
   $this->getFormFactory()->getFormElementManager()->get(\Application\Fieldset\Outline::class);
}
```

And of course you can use it's name in your factory-backed form extensions.

**BUT** if you create it via `new` keyword, your factory will not be triggered.