# Howto fill a select element in a fieldset from a database (mysql)

Tags: zend-framework3

I'm new to Zend framework and trying to populate a select field in a fieldset within a form. I have followed various links but none seem to succeed.

I have two tables Item & Category, the category id exists as a foreign key in the item table. I am trying to load the available categories for selection in either Edit or Add mode.

I used these as a base

[How to trigger fieldset factory in ZF3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49097075/how-to-trigger-fieldset-factory-in-zf3/49128694)

[ZF3 - Populate Select from Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609300/zf3-populate-select-from-database)

Fieldset factory

```
class ItemFieldsetFactory implements FactoryInterface {
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null) {
        $category = $container->get(CategoryRepository::class);
        $categories = $category->findAllCategoriesAsArray();

        $fieldset = $container->get('FormElementManager')->get(\Form\ItemFieldset::class);
        $fieldset->setCategories($categories);

        return $fieldset;
    }
}
```

Fieldset

```
namespace Item\Form;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\Form\Element\Select;
use Item\Model\Item;
use Zend\Hydrator\ReflectionHydrator as ReflectionHydrator;

class ItemFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    private $categories = [];

    public function setCategories(array $categories) {
         $this->categories = $categories;
    }


    public function init()
    {
        $this->setHydrator(new ReflectionHydrator());
    $this->setObject(new Item('', '', '', ''));

        $this->add([
           'type' => 'hidden',
           'name' => 'itemid',
        ]);

        $this->add([
           'type' => Select::class,
           'name' => 'categoryid',
           'options' => [
                'label' => 'Category',
                'value_options' => $this->categories
           ]
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'description',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Description',
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'size',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Size',
            ],
        ]);

    }
}
```

Controller factory

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $formManager = $container->get('FormElementManager');

        return new WriteController(
            $container->get(ItemCommandInterface::class),
            $formManager->get(ItemForm::class),
            $formManager->get(ItemFieldset::class),
            $container->get(ItemRepositoryInterface::class)
        );
    }
}
```

Controller

```
{
    private $command;
    private $form;
    private $fieldset;
    private $repository;

/**
 * @param ItemCommandInterface $command
 * @param ItemForm $form
 */
    public function __construct(
        ItemCommandInterface $command,
        ItemForm $form,
        ItemFieldset $fieldset,
        ItemRepositoryInterface $repository
    ) {
        $this->command = $command;
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->fieldset = $fieldset;
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function addAction()
{
    $req   = $this->getRequest();
    $viewModel = new ViewModel(['form' => $this->form]);

    if (! $req->isPost()) {
        return $viewModel;
    }

    $this->form->setData($req->getPost());

    if (! $this->form->isValid()) {
        return $viewModel;
    }

    $item = $this->form->getData();

    try {
        $item = $this->command->insertItem($item);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        // An exception occurred; we may want to log this later and/or
        // report it to the user. For now, we'll just re-throw.
        throw $ex;
    }

    return $this->redirect()->toRoute(
        'item/detail',
        ['itemid' => $item->getItemId()]
    );
}
```

Config

```
namespace Item;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\Form;
use Zend\Fieldset;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'service_manager' => [
..
    ],
    'controllers' => [
..
    ],
    'router' => [
..
    ],
    'form_elements' => [
        'factories' => [
            Form\ItemFieldset::class => Factory\ItemFieldsetFactory::class
        ]
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

I was hoping the select field would contain all the available categories (in edit mode with the current one selected).

All I get is a blank box

I think my ItemFieldsetFactory is not triggering but cannot understand why. My reason for this is I have tried to stop at this point by call a non-existent method and also by vardump & exit.

Any advice/guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: `also by vardump & exit` ouch. If you're developing locally, follow [this guide by Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html) or [this one with Docker](https://www.pascallandau.com/blog/setup-phpstorm-with-xdebug-on-docker/). - Using xdebug will save you an incredible amount of time placing those `var_dump($var);exit;` lines, refreshing, inspecting, editing and repeating by giving you, instead, the option to halt execution, inspect during execution and test changes during execution.

Comment: These lines: `$this->setHydrator(new ReflectionHydrator()); $this->setObject(new Item('', '', '', ''));`, do that in your Factory with `$fieldsetVar->setHydrator((new Hydrator())->setObject(new Category());`. Unless this can change, you might as well, as it changes nothing for the fieldset content creation logic (which is what you do in the class)

Comment: Further, judging by the function names, you should be able to get results (ie. categories) as options in the fieldset. That is, if your `$categories` property is an array of just values, you should have the values as text options and numeric keys as value options in the HTML output. If you've defined key/value pairs then those should be present. If `findAllCategoriesAsArray` returns an array of objects, then you need to convert those, possibly with an anonymous function when setting on the Select element. Can you confirm your situation on that?

Comment: Many thanks for all the advice I will certainly look into the guide from  (I thought there must be a better way to achieve it).

Comment: {
        $sql       = new Sql($this->db);
        $select    = $sql->select('categories');
        $select->order('description');
        $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
        $result    = $statement->execute();

        if (! $result instanceof ResultInterface || ! $result->isQueryResult()) {
            return [];
        }

        $resultSet = new HydratingResultSet($this->hydrator, $this->categoryPrototype);
        $resultSet->initialize($result);
        $arrayResults = $resultSet->toArray();

        return ($arrayResults);
    }

Comment: Added the findAllCategoriesAsArray.

Are you saying I need to parse the result creating key/value pairs

Comment: Yes. (By the way, placing an edit with additional information in the question is much easier readable than as a comment). - But yes, the final result of `'value_options' => $here,` must have a key/value array in place of `$here`. So `['foo' => 'bar', 'space' => 'astronaut'']` gives 2 options (1 - value 'foo' with text 'bar', 2 value 'space' with text 'astronaut').

Comment: Many thanks, realised that as soon as I had pressed enter. Every day is a school day!

Comment: All good. Post a solution when you've got it working ;-)